# Deploy application on Activemq

Tags: java, activemq-classic

I wrote an easy messaging application using Maven for Spring on Eclipse.
I have built the .war file via Maven, but i dont have a clue about how to get it running.
I have the Activemq server running with it's queues. But i dont know where to locate the war file so it starts running
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you can deploy your war inside the AMQ instance. It sounds more like you would be  looking for an application server such as [Tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org/), where you would deploy the .war file to start it.

Comment: It is possible to put your ActiveMQ onto the Tomcat server as well.  That way you will have one application server and it will simply have two webapps running on it.